# how can you Given two integers a and b, which can be positive or negative,and find the sum of all the numbers between including them too and return it

Tags: javascript, integer

function getSum( a , b){
} //so how do you get along this

Answer (score 0):

A `for-loop` does the sum.

*Assuming a < b*

```js
let sum = 0,
    a = -3,
    b = 4;
    
for (let i = a; i <= b; i++) {
  sum += i;
}

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to create a loop between a and b and add all of them in a 3rd variable.

But first, you need to determine what is the start and the end of the loop, I create a `min`, `max` var for that depending if a > b or not and loop from `min` to `max`:

```js
function getSum(a, b) {
  const min = a < b ? a : b;
  const max = a < b ? b : a;

  let sum = 0;
  for(let i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    sum += i;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: The min and max condition is the other way round.Your min and max both are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just start a loop from the lowest number till the highest number. Keep on adding all the numbers and return the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Just we need to identify the start and end index. and you can default your result to 0, otherwise you may get NaN error.

```
function getSum(a, b) {
var startindex = a > b ? b : a;
var endindex = a > b ? a : b;

var result = 0;
for(var i = startindex; i <=  endindex; i++) {
result = result + i;
}
return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply use the formula in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842152/finding-the-sum-of-numbers-between-any-two-given-numbers) topic. This doesn't even require to use a for loop. In your code you use a instead of alpha and b instead of beta.

```js
var num_1 = 20;
var num_2 = 30;

console.log( getSum(num_1, num_2) );

function getSum(a,b) {
    return (a+b)*(b-a+1)/2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   const GetSum = (a, b) => {
      let min = Math.min(a, b),
      max = Math.max(a, b);
     return (max - min + 1) * (min + max) / 2;
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged. Please [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69638612/edit) to explain how/why the code solves the problem. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/30123823)